# Filter Combobox binding source data from another

Tags: c#, asp.net, dapper

I have two comboboxes, both with binding sources attached which are pre-populated with data from a SQL server;

```
    private void SetLocationAreaBindingSource()
    {
        cboLocationArea.DisplayMember = "name";
        cboLocationArea.ValueMember = "areaID";

        DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@LocationType", 4);
        locationAreaBindingSource.DataSource = db.Query<LocationArea>("LocationAreas_GetWhereType", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }

    private void SetLocationBayBindingSource()
    {
        cboLocationBay.DisplayMember = "name";
        cboLocationBay.ValueMember = "bayID";

        locationBayBindingSource.DataSource = db.Query<LocationBay>("SELECT * FROM [LocationBays] ORDER BY [name] ASC", commandType: CommandType.Text);
    }
```

When the user selects a value in the first combobox (cboLoacationArea) I need to filter the results down in cboLocationBay to only show the results related to that area;

```
    private void cboLocationArea_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        locationBayBindingSource.Filter = "[locationAreaID] = " + cboLocationArea.SelectedValue;
        cboLocationBay.Refresh();
    }
```

however the above code doesnt seem to work and just shows the full list. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is the event wired up?  If you debug it, does that code run?  No reason to call `cboLocationBay.Refresh();` in the SelectedIndexChanged event for that control.

Comment: Its all hooked up and the code is being ran, but the results are not filtering

Comment: you're using Dapper?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I don’t know if it helps, but the selected value will be of type in (areaID) and locationAreaID is also of type int. do I need to format the string and then cast/convert or does this not matter?

Answer (score 1):

You must use IBindingListView interface to support [filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter?view=netframework-4.8) in this case [DataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=netframework-4.8).

> DataView:
>
> Represents a databindable, customized view of a DataTable for sorting, filtering, searching, editing, and navigation. The DataView does not store data, but instead represents a connected view of its corresponding DataTable. Changes to the DataView's data will affect the DataTable. Changes to the DataTable's data will affect all DataViews associated with it.

I think your better approach will be to use *Dapper* and implement the **IDataReader** API the framework itself has:

```
private void SetLocationBayBindingSource()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    var reader = db.ExecuteReader<LocationBay>("SELECT * FROM [LocationBays] ORDER BY [name] ASC", commandType: CommandType.Text);
    dt.Load(reader);
    locationBayBindingSource.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

    cboLocationBay.DisplayMember = "name";
    cboLocationBay.ValueMember = "bayID";
    cboLocationBay.DataSource = locationBayBindingSource;
}
```

Later then you don't need to refresh the ComboBox, the changes to the datatable will affect the dataview as the documentation says.
(I will interpolate the string)

```
private void cboLocationArea_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    locationBayBindingSource.Filter = $"[locationAreaID] = {cboLocationArea.SelectedValue}";
}
```

Comment: I receive an error on ExecuteReader as db is set using;

SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ObsidianDB"].ConnectionString);

Comment: You need to post how the connection to database is implemented

Comment: Yes sorry, I have the above set at the top of the form class and then the setting of the combo-boxes are done during form initialization. The database connection is then stored within my configuration manager as; <add name ="ObsidianDB" connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-#######\MANUFACTURINGSQL;Database=ManufacturingDatabase;User=####;Pwd=#######;"/>

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-bind the datasource again:

```
private void cboLocationArea_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    locationBayBindingSource.Filter = "[locationAreaID] = " + cboLocationArea.SelectedValue;
    cboLocationBay.Items.Clear();
    cboLocationBay.DataSource = locationBayBindingSource.DataSource;
    // cboLocationBay.Refresh();  // this may not be necessary
}
```

Comment: It didn’t unfortunately, I am unsure if it is something to do with dapper. I ended up using the old way with data adapter and table and not using a binding source object and it is now working. I think I need to do some more reading into dapper, but I very much appreciate your assistance!